# Android finish Activity and start another one

Tags: android, android-activity, stack

I'm curious about one thing. How can I finish my current activity and start another one.

Example :

```
MainActivity
    --(starts)--> LoginActivity
        --(if success, starts)--> SyncActivity
            --(if success start)--> MainActivity (with updated data).
```

So I want when `SyncActivity` starts `MainActivity` after succesfull sync and if I press back button not to return to `SyncActivity` or any other activity opened before `SynActivity`.

I've tried with this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Synchronization.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivity(intent);
this.finish();
```

but it's not working properly. Any ideas how to get the things to work properly?

Comment: what does "at the same time" means?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SyncActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Ohh mighty flags, y u so undiscovered... (-

Comment: Take note that when you don't explicitly call `finish();` the `onDestroy()` lifecycle method will not be called after `startActivity(intent);`.

Comment: Do not ignore @heyarne 's comment if you're dealing with ViewModel. If ``onDestroy()`` is not called, then ViewModel is still alive since ``onCleared()`` gets called only after the former. That can result in unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

Judging from your OP, I'm not sure if you absolutely must initialize your mainActivity twice..

Android is designed so that an app is never really closed by the user. 
Concentrate on overriding the android lifecycle methods such as OnResume and OnPause to save UI data, etc.

Hence, you don't need to explicitly `finish()` the main activity (and really shouldn't). To receive login or sync data from the previous activities, just override the `OnActivityResult()` method. However, to do this you must start the activity using `startActivityForResult(intent)`. So for each activity you should do this:

Main activity:

```
static public int LOGIN_RETURN_CODE = 1;
```

to start login:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogInActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, LOGIN_RETURN_CODE);
```

to recieve login info:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
      case LOGIN_RETURN_CODE:
        //do something with bundle attached
    }
}
```

Login activity:

```
static public int SYNC_RETURN_CODE = 2;
```

to start sync:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LogInActivity.this, SyncActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,SYNC_RETURN_CODE);
```

to recieve info and return to Main:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
          case MainActivity.SYNC_RETURN_CODE:
            Intent intent = new Intent(...);
            intent.setResult(RESULT_OK);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

This might not all compile, but hopefully you get the idea.