# How to close the 'Activity Home' when i was in 'Activity Details'?

Tags: android, android-activity

I got three Activity namely 'Acitvity Login', 'Activity Home' and 'Activity Details'

I go from  'Acitvity Login' to 'Activity Home' and mean time i will close 'Acitvity Login'
from 'Activity Home' i will go to 'Activity Details' but i dont close 'Activity Home' since i may have to go back to 'Activity Home'
In 'Activity Details' i have a button for logout and on click of this button i have to go 'Acitvity Login' 
NOw, my question is how to close 'Activity Home' when i was in 'Activity Details'?

Thanks,

Nandakishore P

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469023/android-outofmemory-error-and-the-backstack/20680484#20680484

Comment: thanks  Kanwaljit Singh

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in `Activity Details`:

```
public static ActivityA instance = null;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    instance = this;
}

@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
    instance = null;
}
```

then in Acitvity Login:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(ActivityA.instance != null) {
        try {  
            ActivityA.instance.finish(); 
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when you call another activity,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.Class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish(); //<- this is the command that "closes" your current activity
```

Read more about it to apply code better depending on your requirement:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html
[How to finish Activity when starting other activity in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957125/how-to-finish-activity-when-starting-other-activity-in-android)
[Android finish Activity and start another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599955/android-finish-activity-and-start-another-one)

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this:

define a **static instance** in Activity Home,

in the Activity Details you can finish the Activity Home like this:

```
ActivityHome.instance.finish();
```